# Write query for select first record of status 1 & second record of status 2 and so on

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query for selecting first record of status 1 & second record of status 2 and so on

I've table like

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id |   name | status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   ABC  |      1 |
|  2 |   PQR  |      1 |
|  3 |   qqq  |      2 |
|  4 |   www  |      1 |
|  5 |   eee  |      2 |
|  6 |   rrr  |      2 |
|  7 |   ttt  |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I need an output like below

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id |  name |  status |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 |   ABC |       1 |
|  3 |   qqq |       2 |
|  2 |   PQR |       1 |
|  5 |   eee |       2 |
|  4 |   www |       1 |
|  6 |   rrr |       2 |
|  7 |   ttt |       2 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

the sequence of records should like that

```
- 1st record with status 1
- 2nd record with status 2
- 3rd record with status 1
- 4th record with status 2
- 5th record with status 1
- 6th record with status 2
```

> - 7th record with status 2 -> if we not find any record with status 1 then select records with status 2 & vice versa

I've get this output through coding but it's possible MySQL query to get such output

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the ordering you want with the output.

Comment: @raushankumar It's not duplicate question. you are referencing on even/odd records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT id, name, status
FROM (
   SELECT id, name, status,
       @grp := IF(@status = status, @grp + 1, 
                  IF(@status := status, 1, 1)) AS grp
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @status := 0) AS vars
   ORDER BY status, name) AS t
ORDER BY grp, status, name
```

The key in the algorithm used is variable `@grp`: it essentially simulates `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status)`. Using `@grp` we can easily achieve the *order by alternating* `status` effect.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WFCR87932)

Comment: For some reason not clear, at least not to me, rextester doesn't work well with MySQL variables.

Comment: Upvote, in fact, rextester does work, `@status = 0` should be `@status := 0`, and see [this](http://rextester.com/WFVXJO91449).

Comment: @Forward Good catch! I 've added the rextester demo in my post.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Thanks it gives the records as per my requirment.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @row:=0;
SET @row2:=0;

(SELECT @row:=@row+1, id, `name`, status FROM mytable WHERE status = 1)
UNION
(SELECT @row2:=@row2+1, id, `name`, status FROM mytable WHERE status = 2)
ORDER BY 1, 4;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this query`SELECT rownum FROM TABLE GROUP BY rownum HAVING mod(rownum,2)=0`

Comment: There is no rownum in mysql

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.